# Scala/Sbt project on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

It's been a while since I used Scala and Intellij. But I wanted to learn about Big Data, and I decided to start a course.

I have been trying to setup IntelliJ to run the first project. I installed openjdk 16 and scala 2.12.13.

I am able to run the project from terminal

$ sbt clean compile run

In IntelliJ I created an sbt task with the same commands, but I am getting the following error.

```
[info] running com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming.PrintTweets 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error]   at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1006)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:639)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setMaster(SparkConf.scala:115)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.updatedConf(SparkContext.scala:2698)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:862)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:101)
[error]   at com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming.PrintTweets$.main(PrintTweets.scala:24)
[error]   at com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming.PrintTweets.main(PrintTweets.scala)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @3d8f7200
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1006)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:639)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setMaster(SparkConf.scala:115)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.updatedConf(SparkContext.scala:2698)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:862)
[error]   at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:101)
[error]   at com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming.PrintTweets$.main(PrintTweets.scala:24)
[error]   at com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming.PrintTweets.main(PrintTweets.scala)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[error]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Apr 8, 2021, 8:17:21 AM
```

I am stuck, I have been trying to vary the setup, delete the `.idea` folder and invalidate cache/restart intellij. But I am always getting the same error.

Comment: openjdk 16 and scala 2.12.13? I'm not sure about that. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/ "Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, Python 3.6+ and R 3.5+. Java 8 prior to version 8u92 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.0.0. For the Scala API, Spark 3.1.1 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)."

Comment: @Twistleton, thanks for your comment, I was able to run the project on Intellij, I have to install a plugin to be able to switch between Java versions because it was like stuck on version 16. Thanks!

Comment: @yangzai thanks for your comment, I was using Scala 2.12.13, but my mistake was to be using openjdk 16. Thanks!